# App name showing as __RN_CONFIG_DISPLAY_NAME on iOS

Tags: react-native, react-native-config

I'm using react-native-config in my ReactNative app. After upgrading react-native-config to 1.4.5 and React Native to 0.66.1, everything worked well, but app name in iOS showing as __RN_CONFIG_DISPLAY_NAME.

Does anyone else have this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed __RN_CONFIG_DISPLAY_NAME to $(APP_DISPLAY_NAME) in info.plist and problem solved!